# CSS HTML white space torture

Tags: html, css

How can I get rid of this white space between "Services we provide" and "Meet our team"? http://prntscr.com/8mrj1p

Source code's

http://pastebin.com/Xjj8vaFK

http://pastebin.com/nwHbNFSz

Comment: can you give us the link of your site instead?

Comment: Looks like it's part of the image. You can redo the image or use some creative techniques to overcome the problem. `<img id="screenshot-image" class="image__pic js-image-pic" alt="" src="http://i.imgur.com/mLtVmy8.png">` is the culprit.

Comment: This is the beta site, Mister.
http://www.nikoladeveloper.x3.rs/psdproj/novipsd.html

Comment: @nidza see my answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this... set the height of the div to 0px;

```
#servicesicons {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 0px;
}
```

Comment: @nidza np... don't forget to upvote and check if this answer helps you.